# will there be any problem in adding multiple head tag into php dynamic page?

Tags: php, dynamic-pages

Some pages are dynamically generated and for that page I want to set title dynamically from database. The problem (actually not) is page layout is virtually broken by `app_top, header.php, content.php, footer.php` and so on.

All basic tags which should be in head tags are defined in `app_top.php` page. Database code is in `content.php` so I cant set title tag dynamically. While trying different method I came up with adding another head tag at the end in `footer.php` and added title tag and removed from previous which was in `app_top.php.`

Page is rendering properly. I want to know whether multiple head tags will cause any problem by any way (for web crawlers etc.).

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know whether multiple head tags will cause any problem by any way

Absolutely don't do this. Multiple `head` sections are not valid HTML, and can lead to unpredicable behaviour. Most browsers will somehow leniently work around them and render the document anyway (as far as possible), but this creates a lot of problems in the long run - for example, you will hardly be able to diagnose other HTML problems because you have such a broken document structure.

The best workaround is usually to modify the application's architecture so you have the opportunity to change the title before any HTML gets rendered.

Comment: at least can I add script tag to the end of the page and add title element to head tag(app_top.php) ?

Comment: @kiran theoretically yes, but it's  not a good idea IMO - search engines won't pick that up, for example.